# Not able to access gridview inside tab panel from code behind asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, tabs

I have a gridview to which I am allocating a data source and binding it on Button Click in Code behind.

Code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource=List;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

asp.net

It was working fine until I decided to put this grid view inside a tab panel. As soon as I put the gridview inside the tab it is not able to access the gridview.

I tried using FindControl to find GridView3 but its not working.

Can somebody suggest me a work around?

Thanks

Comment: "I tried using FindControl to find GridView3 but its not working." means what ??it gives any error?You can loop through all the controls inside tab panel and find your gridview control..

Comment: Can you just show us the aspx code???

Comment: @BibekGautam it worked when I looped through tabs. Can you post this as your answer I will mark it as my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try looping over all the containers in tab-panel:

```
foreach(var c in tab_panel.Controls)
{
   if(c is your control)
     return c;

   if(c is a container)
     loop through all controls in c;//recursion
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:`TabPanel.Children?`